# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType' libpng warning: grAb: CRC error

Tags: python, pygame

Пишу код по игре и вдруг начала вылетать эта ошибка. Кто поможет помочь? Пожалуйста, очень надо.

(Не стал включать сюда пол кода со спрайтами т.к это не надо)

Код выдаёт ошибку в строчке где я пометил звёздочкой (*)

```
@property
def sprite_shot(self):
    return min([obj.is_on_fire for obj in self.list_of_objects], default=(float('inf'), 0))
```

class SpriteObject:

```
def __init__(self, parameters, pos):
    self.object = parameters['sprite'].copy()
    self.viewing_angles = parameters['viewing_angles']
    self.shift = parameters['shift']
    self.scale = parameters['scale']
    self.animation = parameters['animation'].copy()
    # ---------------------
    self.death_animation = parameters['death_animation'].copy()
    self.is_dead = parameters['is_dead']
    self.dead_shift = parameters['dead_shift']
    # ---------------------
    self.animation_dist = parameters['animation_dist']
    self.animation_speed = parameters['animation_speed']
    self.blocked = parameters['blocked']
    self.flag = parameters['flag']
    self.obj_action = parameters['obj_action'].copy()
    self.x, self.y = pos[0] * TILE, pos[1] * TILE
    self.side = parameters['side']
    self.dead_animation_count = 0
    self.animation_count = 0
    self.npc_action_trigger = False
    if self.viewing_angles:
        if len(self.object) == 8:
            self.sprite_angles = [frozenset(range(338, 361)) | frozenset(range(0, 23))] + \
                                 [frozenset(range(i, i + 45)) for i in range(23, 338, 45)]
        self.sprite_positions = {angle: pos for angle, pos in zip(self.sprite_angles, self.object)}

@property
def is_on_fire(self):
    if CENTER_RAY - self.side // 2 < self.current_ray < CENTER_RAY + self.side // 2 and self.blocked:
        return self.distance_to_sprite, self.proj_height
    return float('inf'), None

@property
def pos(self):
    return self.x - self.side // 2, self.y - self.side // 2

def object_locate(self, player):

    dx, dy = self.x - player.x, self.y - player.y
    self.distance_to_sprite = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)

    self.theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    gamma = self.theta - player.angle
    if dx > 0 and 180 <= math.degrees(player.angle) <= 360 or dx < 0 and dy < 0:
        gamma += DOUBLE_PI
    self.theta -= 1.4 * gamma

    delta_rays = int(gamma / DELTA_ANGLE)
    self.current_ray = CENTER_RAY + delta_rays
    self.distance_to_sprite *= math.cos(HALF_FOV - self.current_ray * DELTA_ANGLE)

    fake_ray = self.current_ray + FAKE_RAYS
    if 0 <= fake_ray <= FAKE_RAYS_RANGE and self.distance_to_sprite > 30:
        self.proj_height = min(int(PROJ_COEFF / self.distance_to_sprite * SCALE), DOUBLE_HEIGHT)
        sprite_width = int(self.proj_height * self.scale[0])
        sprite_height = int(self.proj_height * self.scale[1])
        half_sprite_width = sprite_width // 2
        half_sprite_height = sprite_height // 2
        shift = half_sprite_height * self.shift

        if self.is_dead and self.is_dead != 'immortal':
            sprite_object = self.dead_animation()
            shift = half_sprite_height * self.dead_shift
            sprite_height = int(sprite_height / 1.3)
        elif self.npc_action_trigger:
            sprite_object = self.npc_in_action()
        else:
            self.object = self.visible_sprite()
            sprite_object = self.sprite_animation()

        # sprite scale and pos
        sprite_pos = (self.current_ray * SCALE - half_sprite_width, HALF_HEIGHT - half_sprite_height + shift)
        sprite = pygame.transform.scale(sprite_object, (sprite_width, sprite_height))
        return (self.distance_to_sprite, sprite, sprite_pos)
    else:
        return (False,)

def sprite_animation(self):
    if self.animation and self.distance_to_sprite < self.animation_dist: (* тут ошибка)
        sprite_object = self.animation[0]
        if self.animation_count < self.animation_speed:
            self.animation_count += 1
        else:
            self.animation.rotate()
            self.animation_count = 0
        return sprite_object
    return self.object

def visible_sprite(self):
    if self.viewing_angles:
        if self.theta < 0:
            self.theta += DOUBLE_PI
        self.theta = 360 - int(math.degrees(self.theta))

        for angles in self.sprite_angles:
            if self.theta in angles:
                return self.sprite_positions[angles]
    return self.object

def dead_animation(self):
    if len(self.death_animation):
        if self.dead_animation_count < self.animation_speed:
            self.dead_sprite = self.death_animation[0]
            self.dead_animation_count += 1
        else:
            self.dead_sprite = self.death_animation.popleft()
            self.dead_animation_count = 0
    return self.dead_sprite

def npc_in_action(self):
    sprite_object = self.obj_action[0]
    if self.animation_count < self.animation_speed:
        self.animation_count += 1
    else:
        self.obj_action.rotate()
        self.animation_count = 0
    return sprite_object
```

Comment: Пробовали переводить ошибку? Что получилось? Раз сами пишите то не должно  быть проблем со столь тривиальными проблемами

Comment: Забыл уточнить что пишу по видео. Но в видео у человека не возникло ошибки. Ошибку переводил, но не могу понять почему.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста помочь. Если можете.

Comment: Я понимаю что что-то связано с этой строчкой, наверное - return self.distance_to_sprite, self.proj_height
    return float('inf'), None наверное,  но не могу понять почему

Comment: Поможете пожалуйста, мне правда очень надо. Но я не могу понять в чём здесь ошибка.

Comment: Всю информацию об ошибке покажите.

Comment: Щас, пару минуточек. Загружается пайчарм.

Comment: Если быть очень подробным то вот

Comment: File "D:\newgame32\sprite_objects.py", line 176, in object_locate
    sprite_object = self.sprite_animation()
  File "D:\newgame32\sprite_objects.py", line 186, in sprite_animation
    if self.animation and self.distance_to_sprite < self.animation_dist:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'
libpng warning: grAb: CRC error